# Крутые таблицы?

Tags: php, yii2

Мне надо сделать одну очень большую таблицу. Заказчики хотят чтоб было "как в Access, потому что они привыкли с ним работать". Абсолютно все поля из всех таблиц в бд отрендерить на одной странице. И вывести туда все записи. И чтобы при этом еще и смотрелось читабельно, а не приходилось горизонтально скроллить. Должна быть возможность быстрого поиска по полю, сортировки по полю, выбора отображаемых столбцов (типа пометить галочкой нужные) и т.д. и т.п. Кажется обычный GridView так не умеет. Есть ли какие-то настолько крутые виджеты? Необязательно из стандартных, у меня уже используются несколько сторонних. Или что еще посоветуете для этих целей? Может на JS как-то это сделать? Мне например вот [эту](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs) либу советовали, но она такая здоровая и сложная... :(

Comment: мы пользуемся datatables jquery

Comment: @Mcile хорошая штука, может быть попробую. Вроде выглядит несложно.

Answer (score 0):

Ну вообще Extjs офигенный фреймворк для бизнес приложений... Я работаю удаленно и в основном с американскими заказчиками... Так у нас практически все проекты на этом фреймворке...

1. Если разобраться то он не сложный и очень офигенный. В том плане что делать можно все что душе угодно практически. И на самом деле практически не приходится писать код, Особенно в последних версиях где есть binds.
2. Он очень дорогой =) 9к $ годовая лицензия=) но есть и бесплатная открытая лицензия, правда нельзя использовать ее в коммерческих целях как я понял.

Ну это так для справки, а вообще посмотри на Krajee виджеты для yii2

http://demos.krajee.com/dynagrid-demo